# Apply a function into multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| SN | DC |
| --- | --- |
| city | city |
| county | county |
| emailaddress | emailaddress |
| loan number | loaninformation |
| phonenumber | phonenumber |

I want to apply a cosdis function which gets SN and DC columns as inputs. For example cosdis('city','city'), etc.

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    cw = Counter(word)
    sw = set(cw)
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]
```

So I am doing this:
df['cosSim'] = df.apply(lambda x: cosdis(word2vec(x.SN),word2vec(x.DC)), axis = 1)

I am getting this result:

| SN | DC | cosSim |
| --- | --- | --- |
| city | city | 0.707107 |
| county | county | 0.774597 |
| emailaddress | emailaddress | 0.912871 |
| loan number | loaninformation | 0.548703 |
| phonenumber | phonenumber | 0.888523 |

However, when I only put the inputs directly to the function, I am getting different results. For example the output for print(cosdis(word2vec('city'),word2vec('city'))) is 1.

Any suggestions on what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe create normal `for`-loop to get every row with `SN,DC` separatelly.

Comment: if you get wrong result then first you could use `print()` to check values in variables in `word2vec` and `cosdis` - maybe they get different values then you expect - and with `print()` you may see it. It is called `'print debuging'`

Comment: sorry, unable to reproduce. I am getting the expected result with `df.apply`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just realized that there were spaces in the original data. That was messing up the results. I just removed the spaces from both columns and now everything looks fine.